# Can I use mouse click to focus on Byobu splits?

Tags: byobu

I know Byobu is a terminal multiplexer and mouse is not a priority, but I still would like to know if there is a way to focus on a split using mouse click instead of keyboard shortcuts.

In negative case, it certainly would be a great feature.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, this is very much possible.

You simply need to turn on mouse support in your `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` configuration.

Add the following:

```
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-utf8 on
```

This will allow you to:

- select a split by clicking in it
- select a window by clicking on it in your status bar
- resize a split by grabbing the border and dragging

However, you may now find it difficult to use your mouse to click on some text, and highlight (select) it.  To do this, you'll now need to use either <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LeftClick</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Does it work with byobu 5.21 tmux 1.7? I edit `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`, opened a new terminal with byobu but still can't have mouse interaction.

Comment: Ok. It's working now, I just had to restart my terminal :) Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work anymore in Ubuntu 16.04 I guess. I keep getting unknown option for each of one of these options. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: No longer works. See comment below from jig

Answer (score 21):

In Ubuntu 16.04 this solution no longer works. It seems that config has changed in tmux new version ([from tmux 2.1 and up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187900/tmux-enabling-mouse-support-across-different-versions)).

Now you must copy (append) the following in your `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` file:

```
set -g mouse on
set -g mouse-utf8 on
```

Comment: This also works when running tmux on OS X

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 18.04 as well

Answer (score 2):

for me, neither of the above solutions seemed to do anything.

Restarting the terminal session, and restarting byobu with those settings in the config file did nothing.

One magic keypress changed all that:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> and you get the message "Mouse: ON"

(Ubuntu 18.04, tmux 2.6, byobu 5.125)

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to change it in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (Caps C), and enable mouse in the `session options`:

[image]

NOTE: this will only enable the mouse for the current session.